# Program win32 on Windows 8 Pro

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-8

Can I program on Windows 8 Pro for win32 c++ application only If I install Visual C++ 2010 and not visual c++ 2012? Do I need to make any changes for the project to compile the same way like it will be on Vista?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.
no need to change the compilation process.